# "Fit data is empty" when `TH1::SetDefaultSumw2` is on

Tags: c++, root-framework

I have data from a NaI(Tl) detector with a large number of bins and low counts per bin (around 5-30).

I have written this function to extract the data and graph it; however, when I'm attempting to subtract away the background I get "Warning in : Fit data is empty".  This only occurs when I have `TH1::SetDefaultSumw2(kTRUE)` uncommentted.

**Why is this occurring (is my signal too low?)  Can I fix this while still ensuring proper error propagation?**

The data is too long to fit inline; however, I have hosted the files: [Co60](http://xed.space/Co60.TKA) and [Background](http://xed.space/Background.TKA).

The code (file name Graph1.C):

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include "TCanvas.h"
#include "TROOT.h"
#include "TGraphErrors.h"
#include "TH1.h"
#include "TF1.h"
#include "TLegend.h"
#include "TArrow.h"
#include "TLatex.h"

#define NBINS 16384
#define LOWBIN 0
#define HIGHBIN NBINS

using std::vector;
using std::ifstream;

void Graph1(char const* filename, char const* bgfilename, char const* title,
            int start_bin = LOWBIN, int end_bin = HIGHBIN) {
  TH1::SetDefaultSumw2(kTRUE);
  gStyle->SetOptFit();
  std::ifstream in;
  in.open(filename);

  std::ifstream bg;
  bg.open(bgfilename);

  std::string titleString = title + std::string(";Bin;Count");

  TH1D *counts = new TH1D("Counts", titleString.c_str(), NBINS, LOWBIN, HIGHBIN);
  TH1D bgcounts("Bg", "", NBINS, LOWBIN, HIGHBIN);

  int bin = 0;

  while (in.good() && bg.good()) {
    double temp;
    in >> temp;
    counts->AddBinContent(bin, temp);
    bg >> temp;
    bgcounts.AddBinContent(bin, temp);
    ++bin;
  }

  counts->Add(&bgcounts, -1.0);

  TF1 *fit = new TF1("fit", "gaus", start_bin, end_bin);
  counts->Fit(fit, "R");
  counts->GetXaxis()->SetRange(start_bin, end_bin);

  auto mycanvas = new TCanvas();
  mycanvas->SetGrid();

  counts->SetStats(false);
  counts->Draw("C E");

  mycanvas->Update();
  mycanvas->Modified();
}
```

Root is called with:

```
.x Graph1.C("Co60.TKA", "Background.TKA", "Co60", 12200, 13500)
```

Comment: For the benefit of the downvoter and the close voter, who I assume are the same person, I have bolded the statement where I have asked the question.

Comment: A downvote without a comment is really a shame... especially in this low-traffic ROOT department

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved using the "LL" fit parameter:

> An improved Log Likelihood fit in case of very low statistics and when bincontentsare not integers. Do not use this option if bin contents are large (greater than 100).

https://root.cern.ch/root/html534/guides/users-guide/FittingHistograms.html#the-fit-method